# Custom Discount not apply after customer login

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, discount, onestepcheckout

I created the discount programatically by `sales_quote_collect_totals_after event`.

This discount applies only when cart **subtotal greater than 500**. This discount works good in cart page. After customer login, this discount is removed automatically.I tried this [Refer link](https://www.apptha.com/blog/how-to-avoid-merging-old-cart-items-in-magento/), but not working.The below which I used in sales_quote_collect_totals_after event

```
 $discountAmount = 0;
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();

    $quoteitems = $quote->getAllItems();
    foreach ($quoteitems as $item) {
        /*@var $quoteItem Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        $totalprice += $quote->getBaseSubtotal();
        //exit;

    }

    if($$totalprice>500) {
    $discount = 100;
        $total=$quote->getBaseSubtotal();
        $quote->setSubtotal(0);
        $quote->setBaseSubtotal(0);

        $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
        $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(0);

        $quote->setGrandTotal(0);
        $quote->setBaseGrandTotal(0);

        $canAddItems = $quote->isVirtual()? ('billing') : ('shipping'); 
        foreach ($quote->getAllAddresses() as $address) {

            $address->setSubtotal(0);
                $address->setBaseSubtotal(0);

                $address->setGrandTotal(0);
                $address->setBaseGrandTotal(0);

                $address->collectTotals();

                $quote->setSubtotal((float) $quote->getSubtotal() + $address->getSubtotal());
                $quote->setBaseSubtotal((float) $quote->getBaseSubtotal() + $address->getBaseSubtotal());

                $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(
                    (float) $quote->getSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount()
                );
                $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(
                    (float) $quote->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount()
                );

                $quote->setGrandTotal((float) $quote->getGrandTotal() + $address->getGrandTotal());
                $quote->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $quote->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBaseGrandTotal());

            $quote ->save(); 

            $quote->setGrandTotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
            ->setBaseGrandTotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
            ->setSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
            ->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
            ->save(); 

            if($address->getAddressType()==$canAddItems) {

                    $address->setSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount()-$discountAmount);
                    $address->setGrandTotal((float) $address->getGrandTotal()-$discountAmount);
                    $address->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount()-$discountAmount);
                    $address->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $address->getBaseGrandTotal()-$discountAmount);
                if($address->getDiscountDescription() || $address->getDiscountAmount()){
                    $address->setDiscountAmount(-($address->getDiscountAmount()-$discountAmount));
                    $address->setDiscountDescription($address->getDiscountDescription().', Free Samples');
                    $address->setBaseDiscountAmount(-($address->getBaseDiscountAmount()-$discountAmount));
                }
                else {
                    $address->setDiscountAmount(-($discountAmount));
                    $address->setDiscountDescription('Free Samples');
                    $address->setBaseDiscountAmount(-($discountAmount));
                }
                $address->save();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share your code to get more insight

Comment: this code works good and discount is applied in cart page. after customer login discount removed automatically

Comment: Are you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In config.xml , use **load_customer_quote_before** event

```
<load_customer_quote_before>
    <observers>
        <custom_checkout_observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>yourNamespace_yourModule_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>loadCustomerQuote</method>
        </custom_checkout_observer>
    </observers>
</load_customer_quote_before>
```

In observer.php

```
  <?php
    class YourNamespace_YourModule_Model_Observer extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Session {

        public function loadCustomerQuote() {

            $quote =Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
            $quote->getBillingAddress();
            $quote->getShippingAddress();
            $quote->setCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer())
                    ->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)
                    ->collectTotals()
                    ->save();
            return $this;

        }
}
```

the above code will set the customer to quote before merge.Now the custom discount works good after merge quote.